# Cursor blur effect

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

As I was browsing the showcase section in https://greensock.com, I came across this website https://www.powell-studio.com/

that has a cursor blur effect. I tried to replicate it with js, but with no luck.
From my understanding it is using gsap and split type to separate the title, but the blur effect, I still don't understand how its done.

Any suggestions and pointers would be very much appreciated!
Thank you

I tried to split the text title, but with no luck and the blur effect I have no idea how to do.

my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const customCursor = document.querySelector(".lens_cursor");
      const blurTextElement = document.getElementById("blur_text");

      // Track the cursor's position
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        // Update the custom cursor's position
        customCursor.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
        customCursor.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
      });

      // Split the text within the #blur_text element into individual characters
      const splitText = new SplitText(blurTextElement, {
        type: "chars"
      });

      // Animate each character
      splitText.chars.forEach((char) => {
        char.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
          customCursor.classList.add("hovered");
          gsap.to(char, {
            duration: 0.3,
            filter: "blur(5px)"
          });
        });

        char.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
          customCursor.classList.remove("hovered");
          gsap.to(char, {
            duration: 0.3,
            filter: "blur(0px)"
          });
        });
      });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;1,500&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #181818;
  background-color: #e4e1d9;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 99;
  min-height: 8vmin;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 3.125rem;
  padding-right: 3.125rem;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}

.link_group {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 10%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav_link {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
  color: #181818;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_link_home {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
}

.dot {
  min-height: 8px;
  min-width: 8px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #A40808;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_link::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.nav_link:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  background-color: #A40808;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vmin;
  padding-left: 3.125rem;
  padding-right: 3.125rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.hero_title {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 250px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.description {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 54px;
  position: relative;
  top: -55px;
}

#blur_text {
  transition: filter 0.3s ease;
}

.lens_cursor {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@studio-freight/lenis@1.0.23/dist/lenis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="link_group">
      <a href="#" class="nav_link">Archive</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_link">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link_group">
      <a href="#" class="nav_link_home">name<span class="dot"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="link_group">
      <a href="#" class="nav_link">Instagram</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_link">Shop</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="hero">
      <h1 class="hero_title" id="blur_text">My title</h1>
      <p class="description">this is a descrition</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lens_cursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: _"I tried to replicate it with js"_ - you did? Please share that! Create a [mcve] using the `<>` button? The website seems to the canvas to achieve the effect

Comment: Based on a quick glance at the script in Chrome's inspector, it's using WebGL and a shader for the blur effect. See what happens if you delete the element with the id `canvas-wrapper` from the page...

Comment: the whole container dissapears when I remove the id.
so the effect is based on webgl?
Thank you for the answer!!